# Django Wagtail CMS File Too Large for Upload

Tags: django, wagtail

I am using Django Wagtail CMS 1.10.1 and and am getting a file too large when trying to upload images or documents. What I don't understand is that the files are less than 1.5mB.  How do I adjust the limits on permitted upload file sizes to get around this.  Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This size limit is being imposed by your web server, not Wagtail. I'm guessing you're probably using nginx, as that has unusually low size limits by default... if so, you need to increase the [client_max_body_size](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) setting.